# Overload generic List's Add with extension method

Tags: c#, generics

I would like to overload a generic list's Add method so I can use collection initializations like:

```
var x = new List<Tuple<string>> { { "1", "2" }, { "1", "2" } };
```

(Where Tuple is a simple custom implementation of a binary tuple.)
However, I created an extension method, put a using directive in the cs file, and still get the "No overload for method 'Add' takes 2 arguments"-error.
Is it not possible to do (with an extension method)?

Extension method code:

```
namespace ExtensionMethods {
    public static class Extensions{
        public static void Add<T>(this List<Tuple<T>> self, T value1, T value2) {
            self.Add(new Tuple<T> { value1, value2 });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose it is not possible due to a differences in how you want to use it and how object initializations work. Though somebody might have a suggestions on it. Also I doubt object initializers will work with extension methods.

Comment: Interestingly, it appears this **is** supported in [Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293683.aspx)

Comment: There is a connect issue for this, vote if you want to see it added to C# as well: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/459307/extension-add-methods-are-not-considered-in-c-collection-initializers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# 6.0[0] Microsoft allows the use  of extensions methods in collection initializers. hurray :)

And since this isn't a .NET Framework or CLR change, but a compiler change, this feature can be used with .NET 4.0.

So the following is now valid C# code.  (Tested in Visual Studio 2015 RC)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x = new List<Tuple<string,string>> { { "1", "2" }, { "1", "2" } };
    }
}
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void Add<T1,T2>(this List<Tuple<T1,T2>> self, T1 value1, T2 value2)
    {
        self.Add(Tuple.Create( value1, value2 ));
    }
}
```

[C# 6 Features](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2014/11/20/new-features-in-c-6.aspx) [0]

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible via extension methods. In order to make this syntax working you have to create your own collection class which will have `void Add(T value1, T value2)` signature.

P.S.: What you've done is not `overload` and there is no way to overload anything in existing class.

**UPDATE:** Looks like my first sentence should be: "It is not possible via extension methods **in C#**"

Comment: Hmm… I'm trying to add a method to a Type that already has a method with the same name, but with different parameters. If that's not overloading, what is it?

Comment: The reason I'm telling this is because extension methods are not really `added to a Type`. You can invoke them so it will look like they are part of type, but still they won't be a part of it.

Comment: [VB.NET gets all the love.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293683.aspx) :/

Comment: Update^2: Looks like your first sentence should be: "It is not possible via extension methods in C# prior to version 6.0" :D

Answer (score 1):

You cannot implement constructors using extension methods.Extension method is nothing but a static method which takes in an instance of an object. Hence you need to have an instance first to be able to pass to it.

But you can just use `AddRange()` of the List to initialise your list.

Comment: It is not about constructors, it is about collection initializers which requires applicable `Add` method.

Comment: Actually, it is about constructors as  a Tuple instance must be created first before you can add it to a List<Tuple<T>>.

Comment: @Panagiotis, no, it's not about constructors. Tuple constructor has to be invoked but it has almost nothing to do with object initializers.

Comment: No (mostly) and yes. Think what the compiler does behind the scenes. First it checks whether the arguments you pass are objects of type Tuple<T>. If they aren't it searches the collection for an Add method that accepts as many arguments as there arguments in each list of values. If you used a constructor or object initializer the compiler wouldn't try to locate the Add method.

Answer (score 0):

Extension methods can't overload any method defined on their target type simply because they are not members of the target type. Extension methods do not ADD anything to their target types. They are just compiler magic that allow them to be called as if they were methods defined on their target type. In reality, they are defined in a separate static type, hence they can't overload any method on their target type.

Behind the scenes, the compiler replaces any calls to your extension method with a call to Extensions.

It looks like you are trying to make C# behave like Ruby and initialize an array of objects by passing a set of values, or at least imitate the behavior of dictionary initialization. 
Unfortunately you can't do that without actually overloading List<>.

Collection initialization is just another bit of compiler magic that tries to find an Add method with as many arguments as there are items in the argument list. If it were otherwise you could define a conversion operator to convert a list to your Tuple type.

Why don't you just use the built-in object initializers? You'll just have to write a bit more code

Comment: "Why don't you just use the built-in object initializers? You'll just have to write a bit more code"


Exactly. But I use the initializers in the first place to _reduce_ code bloat…